# Remove short synonyms in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

An example like:

```
synonyms_dict = {'look': ['gaze', 'see', 'glance', 'watch', 'peruse'],
'put': ['place', 'set', 'attach', 'keep', 'save', 'set aside', 
'effect', 
'achieve', 'do', 'build'],
'beautiful': ['pretty', 'lovely', 'handsome', 'dazzling', 'splendid', 
'magnificent'],
'slow': ['unhurried', 'gradual', 'leisurely', 'late', 'behind', 'tedious', 
'slack'], 
'dangerous': ['perilous', 'hazardous', 'uncertain']}
remove_short_synonyms(synonyms_dict)
print("1.")
print_dict_in_key_order(synonyms_dict)    
synonyms_dict = {'come': ['approach', 'advance', 'near', 'arrive', 'reach'],
'show': ['display', 'exhibit', 'present', 'point to', 'indicate', 'explain', 
'prove', 'demonstrate', 'expose'],
'good': ['excellent', 'fine', 'superior', 'wonderful', 'grand', 'superb', 
'edifying'],
'bad': ['evil', 'immoral', 'wicked', 'contaminated', 'spoiled', 'defective',  
'substandard', 'faulty', 'improper', 'inappropriate']}
remove_short_synonyms(synonyms_dict)
print("2.")
print_dict_in_key_order(synonyms_dict)
```

I'm trying to remove all the synonyms which have less than 7 characters from each corresponding list of synonyms and the function sorts each corresponding list of synonyms. I tried this function.

```
def remove_short_synonyms(synonyms_dict):
    dicts = list(synonyms_dict.keys())
    for word in sorted(dicts):
        if len(word) <= 7:
           del(synonyms_dict[word])
```

expected:

```
 beautiful : ['dazzling', 'handsome', 'magnificent', 'splendid']
 dangerous : ['hazardous', 'perilous', 'uncertain']
 look : []
 put : ['achieve', 'set aside']
 slow : ['gradual', 'leisurely', 'tedious', 'unhurried']
 2.
 bad : ['contaminated', 'defective', 'immoral', 'improper', 'inappropriate', 
 'spoiled', 'substandard']
 come : ['advance', 'approach']
 good : ['edifying', 'excellent', 'superior', 'wonderful']
 show : ['demonstrate', 'display', 'exhibit', 'explain', 'indicate', 'point 
 to', 'present']
```

Comment: I'd recommend storing a dict of sets, not a dict of lists. Lookup is cheaper.

Comment: You are checking `keys` instead of the synonym list.

Answer (score 1):

don't delete from the original, just rebuild a filtered version using dictionary comprehension, with a max size filter on the values, and feed to `sorted` to sort the value list:

```
synonyms_dict = {'look': ['gaze', 'see', 'glance', 'watch', 'peruse'],
'put': ['place', 'set', 'attach', 'keep', 'save', 'set aside',
'effect',
'achieve', 'do', 'build'],
'beautiful': ['pretty', 'lovely', 'handsome', 'dazzling', 'splendid',
'magnificent'],
'slow': ['unhurried', 'gradual', 'leisurely', 'late', 'behind', 'tedious',
'slack'],
'dangerous': ['perilous', 'hazardous', 'uncertain']}

def remove_short_synonyms(s):
    return {k:sorted([i for i in v if len(i)>7]) for k,v in s.items()}


print(remove_short_synonyms(synonyms_dict))
```

result:

```
{'beautiful': ['dazzling', 'handsome', 'magnificent', 'splendid'], 'look': [], 'dangerous': ['hazardous', 'perilous', 'uncertain'], 'slow': ['leisurely', 'unhurried'], 'put': ['set aside']}
```

Comment: Think you forgot the "function sorts each corresponding list of synonyms" part

Comment: @KaushikNP thanks! once the logic is coded, added a `sorted` is cheap.